# Admob to load when iAds fail

Tags: objective-c, admob, iad

I just added my first free app to the app store with iAds which work ok when the ads load, so I've had a good read up and it seems a better way is to have admob to load when iads fail.
I can get iads working on there own and admob working on there own but not together any help would be great.
I need to get admob to load when didFailToReceiveAdWithError.

my code for iAds

```
    -(void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
 [banner setAlpha:1];
 [UIView commitAnimations];

 }


-(void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
 [banner setAlpha:0];
 [UIView commitAnimations];


}
```

my admob code only seems to work in  [super viewDidLoad];

here my admob code

```
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,
                             self.view.frame.size.height + 2 - CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height); 


bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner origin:origin];


bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;


bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];


[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your code in the iad didFailToReceiveAdWithError code like this

```
-(void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
   [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
   [banner setAlpha:0];
   [UIView commitAnimations];

  //////Admob Code

  CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,
                         self.view.frame.size.height + 2 - CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height); 
  bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner origin:origin];
  bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
  bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
  [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
  [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Thats how i had it But if iads failed, screen just stayed blank & no admob.Ill keep testing maybe i've been unlucky and they both were failing together.